# Programmatical Authentication to Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Morning All, I'm having trouble connecting to Graph API using an Azure Automation account. I’m running the below script through an automation account but it fails to use the stored creds, instead it tries to launch a prompt for credentials, and that’s where the automation account fails.. the script is

The Account username and password have been sored in Azure Automation Account.

```
param( $UserPrincipalName )
    try {
       Import-Module -Name MSGraphIntuneManagement -ErrorAction Stop
       } catch {
        throw 'Prerequisites not installed (AzureAD or MSGraphIntuneManagement PowerShell module not installed'
       }

$IntuneCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name UserName
$IntuneClientId = Get-AutomationVariable -Name SecretValue

$Token = Get-MSGraphAuthenticationToken -Credential $IntuneCredential -ClientId $IntuneClientId

Write-Output "Authenticating to Microsoft Graph API"
$AzureADUser = Get-MSGraphAzureADUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -AuthenticationToken $Token

Write-Output "Found user $($AzureADUser.displayName) in Azure AD"
```

This is authenticating against Intune.

```
$Token = Get-MSGraphAuthenticationToken -Credential $IntuneCredential -ClientId $IntuneClientId
```

Does this `$IntuneCredential` and `$intuneClientId` need to be a registered app or User with Intune Admin in Azure AD?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am curious why you use this way to get the Azure AD user, why not use `Get-AzADUser` or `Get-AzureADUser`?

Comment: @JoyWang Hi, the error I get is that this line tries to launch an interactive box to enter credentials, which is not supported in Azure Automation.

Comment: `$Token = Get-MSGraphAuthenticationToken -Credential $IntuneCredential -ClientId $IntuneClientId`

Comment: Why not use `Get-AzADUser` or `Get-AzureADUser` to get azure ad user?

Comment: @JoyWang Can we use that to authenticate against graphy API and get a token?

Comment: I have never used this module, if you install the module in local and look into its function, you will find it just use adal to get token and call the MS graph which can be easily accomplished via `Get-AzADUser`, so why not choose a better way?

Comment: @JoyWang Thanks for the input, from what I've read in order to authenticate to resource graph API you need to have an access token, which is where `Get-MSGraphAuthenticationToken` comes into it. When I run the function through powershell and explicitly define the URI it errors with missing access token, once I have this I can query the azaduser from intune. Then I would like to run an `Invoke-IntuneSync` through a schedule on an automation account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you used the **MFA-enabled** user account in `$IntuneCredential`. If so, it will not work, as you knew, the runbook in automation does not support the interactive way to input credentials.

In such a scenario, your first option is to use the service principal, but if you want to use [`MSGraphIntuneManagement`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSGraphIntuneManagement/0.2) module, it is not an option, because if you look into the source file of [`Get-MSGraphAuthenticationToken`](https://github.com/janegilring/PSCommunity/blob/master/Azure/Active%20Directory/Get-MSGraphAuthenticationToken.ps1) command, you will find it uses [adal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) to get the token, the code needs the user's credential, so the way is to use a user account without MFA.

Please follow the steps as below.

1.If you did not have a user account without MFA, you could follow this [**doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory#add-a-new-user) to create a new user.

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> 
`New registration` to create a new AD App, details see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).

After creating the app, click the app, follow the screenshot to set it as public client.

[image]

3.Grant the Microsoft Graph API permissions to the AD App.

[image]

[image]

4.Navigate to the automation account in the portal -> `Modules` -> make sure you have installed the `MSGraphIntuneManagement` and `AzureAD` module, if not, go to `Browse gallery`, search and install them.

5.Go to the `Credentials`, store the username and password. Then go to `Variables`, store the `ClientId` of the AD App, you can find it in the `App Registration` -> your AD App.

[image]

6.Then in your runbook, run your script, it will work.

[image]

---

**Note :**

The solution above is just for your original requirement - get the token via `Get-MSGraphAuthenticationToken` to get the user via `Get-MSGraphAzureADUser`. If you need to use other commands in the `MSGraphIntuneManagement` moudle, e.g. `Get-MSGraphIntuneUserDevice`, you need to grant the corresponding API permissions(Delegated permissions) like `step 3` to the AD App. The way is to look into the [source file](https://github.com/janegilring/PSCommunity/blob/master/Azure/Intune/Get-MSGraphIntuneUserDevice.ps1), find the API which the function uses, then find it in the Microsoft Graph Doc and see what permissions it needs.

[image]

After doing some research with the API in the screenshot above, you will find this doc [**Get managedDevice**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-beta) and get the permissions(please note the `$graphApiVersion = "beta"` it used, it is a beta version which I don't recommend you to use it in the production environment.)

[image]

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is get to a place I can run Invoke-AutoPilotSync, but the idea was to first be able to authenticate against the API and then run teh invoke command, is my thinking right?

Comment: Thanks that worked, I was using the wrong user account in the Credentials file. Appreciate your hard work and detailed answer :)